# Android setting default value from Hashmap Key for Spinner in Simple Adapter

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have parsed some `JSON` data from `PHP` and displayed it into a `Spinner`.The data comes with Key-Value. So I used `Hashmap` together with `SimpleAdapter`. Spinner displays only the values. When user selects an item the key will be stored in `MySQL`.

This is my `JSON`,

```
{
    "32":"Western Food",
    "33":"Chinese Food",
    "34":"Mix Food",
    "35":"Japanese Food",
    "36":"Korean Food",
    "37":"Italian Food",
    "38":"German Food",
    "45":"Muslim food ",
    "46":"Indian food"
}
```

For example

Activity A

User add new category, they have choose "Mix Food". When they click submit button, the key - "34" will be stored in database.

[image]

Activity B

```
int get_selected_item_id=34;

List<HashMap<String, String>> category_arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject1.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        String id = iterator.next();
        String name=jsonObject1.getString(id);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id",id);
        map.put("name",name);
        category_arraylist.add(map);

    }

    String[] from = {"name"};
    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(item_edit.this, category_arraylist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, from, to);
    category.setAdapter(adapter);

    category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            category.setSelection(get_selected_item_id); // doesn't work
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

How to display this item as default in Activity B when the spinner shows at the start?

Comment: Use the `setSelection(index)` on spinner to set default item.

Comment: @KNeerajLal it's a typo error. I have changed it. Any idea for my scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model class for your `JSON` data,

```
private class Item {
    String key;
    String value;

    public Item(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Parse your data into this model class,

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject1.keys();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String id = iterator.next();
    String name = jsonObject1.getString(id);
    list.add(new Item(id, name));
}
```

Initialize the `Spinner`,

```
final ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
category.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Find the index of your `get_selected_item_id` in the `list` and use `setSelection` method of `Spinner` to set it as default.

```
int index = findIndexOf(list, get_selected_item_id);
if (index != -1) {
    category.setSelection(index);
}
```

The `findIndexOf` method,

```
private int findIndexOf(List<Item> list, int selectedKey) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getKey().equals(String.valueOf(selectedKey))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The `ItemSelectedListener`,

```
category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        // get selected item using position argument
        Item selectedItem = list.get(position);
        // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```